# Deploy new application to existing container

Tags: docker, docker-container

I have an application that a company is interested in testing in their environment.  Problem is, everything they run is in containers (Docker I believe).  I'm now trying to learn as much as I can on containers because I've never dealt with them before.

My main question is, do their containers need to be rebuilt with my application or is there a mechanism to push the app into existing containers without having to go through a re-build process?  In a small scale test, building new containers isn't going to be an issue but if they decide to scale the deployment up to their whole environment, I'm trying to understand what the impact will be and how to make it work as seamless as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you wouldn't add an application to an existing container, but add your application as a new container. The idea is that a container is basically a single application.

Comment: I understand that but my application works along side some existing applications and can't be segregated in its own microservice.

Comment: could you explain why that is? what does your application do?

Comment: At a high level, telemetry.  It needs access to the processes memory.

Answer (score 0):

Your application runs inside a docker container,you need not push anything into container just you need to create a .dockerfile with all required binaries and dependencies imported properly in required order and build the image from .dockerfile(docker build) and run the image using docker commands(docker run).
    spinning(scaling or creating) up a new container is not a big job and that can be maintained easily by the services provided by your cloud provider kubernetes is the best tool available (IMO) to manage your containers,it takes care of your container instances and scales them as required.